# How to insert elements in 2-D list like vector?

Tags: c++, list, vector, insert, type-2-dimension

So, i have this code here...i tried 2D list and searched for how to insert in 2d list and found nothing.

```
vector<int> dynamicArray(int n, vector<vector<int>> queries) {
vector<int>temp;
list<list<int>>seqList(n);
int lastans=0;
for(int i=0;i<queries.size();i++){
    int x=queries[i][1],y=queries[i][2];
    if(queries[i][0]==1){
        int temp2=(x^lastans)%2;
        seqList[temp2].push_back(y);
    }
    else{
        lastans=seqList[(x^lastans)%2][y];
        temp.push_back(lastans);
    }
}
return temp;
}
```

Now here if i change list<list>seqList(n); to
vector<vector>seqList(n) i get 0 errors and the code works fine

Here's what the error is for using list

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::list<std::__cxx11::list<int> >’ and ‘int’)
         seqList[temp2].push_back(y);
```

so i thought it was the brackets but i am not really sure what the problem is..
i tried using curly brackets and it said:-

```
warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
         seqList{temp2}.push_back(y);
```

Forgive me if i am doing a grave mistake here but,...i couldn't find the solution anywhere and it worked fine with vector

edit:-

I know there is no operator...I want to know how can i insert elements in this 2d list? or is there any other way to insert in 2d list.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::list` is not a `std::vector`. That should not be a big surprise.

If you read documentation for `std::list` (for example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)), you can find that `std::list` has no `operator[]`.

To insert into a list you can use [`std::list::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert).

Note that also if `seqList` is a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` then `operator[]` is not inserting elements. You have

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> seqList(n); // outer vector has n element
seqList[temp2].push_back(y);
      // access element at index temp2 in outer vector
              // push an element to that element
```

Comment: yeah ..i know there is no operator as the code didnt work for any of it ...but i want to know how i can insert elements in 2d list

Comment: ohh that ...no it should work fine with push_back for the list too and it didnt work with insert either ...they almost have the same function 
 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/list-push_back-function-in-c-stl/

Comment: @Shadow sorry I didnt get the question really. Now I think your confusion is coming from `list<list<int>>seqList(n);`. You dont need to insert into the outer list, because you already have `n` entries. You just cant access them via `operator[]` because `std::list` doesn't have one

Comment: yeah ..i wanted to access the outerlist as i had to insert acc to the position of outerlist ...which clearly cant happen..thanks!